# How to get the parent class values and its child collection values in single object in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC application.

I want to get entire object with its child collection when I click on submit button on the form.

Please check below View Model.

I have below view model.

```
       public class AdviceCreateVM
        {      
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string AdviceNo { get; set; }
            public  ICollection<InvoiceVM> Invoices { get; set; }
         }


   public class InvoiceVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I have method create of Paymentadvice controller which accepts the input from view.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AdviceCreateVM AdviceCreateVM,InvoiceVM invoiceVM)
    {
    }
```

in above menthod, I get the values of Invoice collection in the form of array.

but I have req. that, I should get the Advice create and the Invoice collection only in single object. like below method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AdviceCreateVM AdviceCreateVM)
    {
    }
```

How to get that ?

Comment: Create a single model class with all of the properties on it.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering your view, be sure to render out any fields you wish to keep during form submit as a hidden field using something like `Html.HiddenFor()`, if they aren't already represented on the form as an `input`, `select`, `textarea`, etc.

Also when you come to render your repeating element (your invoice), do this in a `for` loop using an index (not a `foreach` loop).  Ideally [create an `EditorFor` template](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/) to render the part of the view responsible for entering each `invoice`.  Again, ensure any fields you wish to carry across during form submission are rendered as hidden fields.

For example:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdviceNo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdviceNo)

@for (var index = 0; index < Model.Invoices.Count; index++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Invoices[index], "_Invoice")
}
```

The editor template ('_Invoice', stored in an 'EditTemplates' folder) would be something like:

```
@model InvoiceVM

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.InvoiceNumber)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceNumber)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TotalAmount)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalAmount)
```

Using editor for templates will also make working with any MVC validation for child objects easier and will avoid some similar pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Parent.FindControl("control_name") as Control_Type
```

For example:

```
HiddenField hdn = Parent.FindControl("hdn") as HiddenField;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create single ViewModel and add these two classes to that model as its fields

```
public class YourViewModel
    {
       public YourViewModel()
       {
        this.adviceCreateVM = new AdviceCreateVM ();
        this.invoiceVM = new InvoiceVM();
       }

       public AdviceCreateVM adviceCreateVM { get; set; }
       public InvoiceVM  invoiceVM { get; set; }
    }
```

Pass this model to view and return it as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(YourViewModel model)
{
//access both classes as model.adviceCreateVM and model.invoiceVM
}
```